# How to add onboarding greeting card for Directline speech client app?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using the following sample Direct line speech client app as a client application for my virtual assistant created using botframework v4. I would like to add an onboarding greeting card in the speech client app when it starts. Is it possible to show the same greeting card that I'm getting while running my bot in the emulator.

Speech client app : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Services-Direct-Line-Speech-Client/releases

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code, all the relevant files (minus any keys/secrets), so we can see what you have tried? Otherwise, it is hard to provide any advice or direction.